# Org table column to string

Tags: org-mode

How do I concatenate a column into a string in Org mode? I want to get `abc` instead of `((a) (b) (c))` as a result. Or is there simply a header that I can tweak?

```
#+name: example-table
| i |
|---|
| a |
| b |
| c |

#+begin_src elisp :var input=example-table
  (format "%s" input)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: ((a) (b) (c))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will work:

```
(mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "%s" (car x))) input)
```

For versions of Emacs earlier than 29, the separator argument to `mapconcat` is mandatory, so the call should be:

```
(mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "%s" (car x))) input "")
;; or...
(mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "%s" (car x))) input nil)
```

specifying an empty string as the separator.

Comment: In addition to your being first to answer, your solution has the advantage of working for columns of numbers (which are not converted to strings by Org mode). But there is a small problem: `t` cannot be used as the name of the variable - it is a reserved symbol in Emacs Lisp. I edited your answer to fix that.

Comment: @NickD thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: This code gives me the followin error `let: Wrong number of arguments: mapconcat, 2`. The documentation mentions a seperator. When call it with `""` as a third argument it works for me

Comment: You are right - earlier versions of mapconcat required a separator argument. Current versions make this argument optional. Edited the answer to mention that.